# Calculate the intersection of graphs in Python

Tags: python, graph

I have two curves (yy0, yy1), which were defined as it follows:

```
import numpy as np

xx=np.arange(x1,x2,1)
yy0=np.zeros(len(xx))
yy1=np.zeros(len(xx))

for i in range (0, len(xx)):
    yy0[i]+=f(xx[i])
    yy1[i]+=g(xx[i])
```

Where f(x) and g(x) are two previously defined functions. Is there a way I can calculate the intersection of the curves/functions?

I've tried different approaches suggested on this website, but so far none have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but it seems like you want `intersection_indices = [ i for i in range(len(xx)) if yy0[i] == yy1[i] ]`.

Keep hacking!  Keep notes!